# PHP read txt-file with pattern and keep information

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for the confusing title, but I can't think of another one.

I have a text-file in this format (just a few lines taken out of context):

```
# Google_Product_Taxonomy_Version: 2015-02-19
1 - Animals & Pet Supplies
3237 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Live Animals
2 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies
3 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies
7385 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories
499954 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories > Bird Cage Bird Baths
7386 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories > Bird Cage Food & Water Dishes
4989 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cages & Stands
4990 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Food
```

So far, so good. I want to write a parser, which contains all the information for each category. After the work is done, it has to be written in a mysql-DB.

There are exactly:

```
1 unique ID
1 Main-category 
n sub-categories
```

The tricky part (for me) is, how to keep those information and save them in an array, with an aspect on the performance.

My DB must have a final output like this

```
ID    | parent | title | 
1     |        | Animals & Pet Supplies
3232  |   1    | Live Animals
2     |   1    | Pet Supplies
3     |   2    | Bird Supplies
```

In fact, I must be able to reproduce this "crumb" pure by my DB-entries.

I started with my parser like this:

```
public function enrichTaxonomy()
{
    $aOutput = array();

    // ignore first line
    fgets($handle);

    // iterate throug it
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
    {
        $splitted = explode("-", $line);

        // build first level
        if (strpos($splitted[1], '>') === false)
        {
            $aOutput['id'][] = trim($splitted[0]);
            $aOutput['title'][] = trim($splitted[1]);
        } else
        {
            // recursive?
            if (substr_count($splitted[1], " > ") == 1)
            {
                $splitted2ndLevel = explode(" > ", $splitted[1]);
                $aOutput['id'][] = trim($splitted[0]);
                $aOutput['title'][] = trim($splitted2ndLevel[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($aOutput);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

But I realized, that this isn't a very good way, since my next step would have been:

```
if (substr_count($splitted[1], " > ") == 2)
{
    $splitted3rdLevel = explode(" > ", $splitted[1]);
    $aOutput['id'][] = trim($splitted[0]);
    $aOutput['title'][] = trim($splitted3rdLevel[2]);
}

if (substr_count($splitted[1], " > ") == 3)
{
    $splitted4thLevel = explode(" > ", $splitted[1]);
    $aOutput['id'][] = trim($splitted[0]);
    $aOutput['title'][] = trim($splitted4thLevel[3]);
}
```

Also, this seems to be very complicated afterwards, when I try to have a final array, which I may then iterate trough to insert this data in my DB.

An important note is, that each "subcategory" has to know its "father", so I can insert the "parent"-id as well.

My question now: 
What is a good, short (in relation), performant way to achieve this?

Comment: I would explode the categories as well and push it in the row array, so you can have an array structure to work with

Comment: @Asur this is what I do in the //resursive-part (which isn't recursive yet). Exploding after each " > " sign to get the "next" category. The output array however doesn't contain the ID anymore

Comment: Then you can push it in the general array so you will have an array for each line with all the data and the categories aswell in a multidimensional array structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to build a tree structure when you will need to flatten it again to insert into the database, instead create the same structure as the db:

```
$input = <<<'EOD'
1 - Animals & Pet Supplies
3237 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Live Animals
2 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies
3 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies
7385 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories
499954 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories > Bird Cage Bird Baths
7386 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories > Bird Cage Food & Water Dishes
4989 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cages & Stands
4990 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Food
EOD;

$dbInput=[];

$lines = explode("\n", $input);
//or for a file, $lines = file('file.path', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($lines as $line){
    if(substr($line, 0, 1) == '#') continue;

    list($id, $crumb) = explode('-', $line);
    $id = trim($id);
    $crumb_parts = array_map('trim',explode('>', $crumb));
    $title = array_pop($crumb_parts);
    $parent = array_pop($crumb_parts);
    $parent_id = isset($dbInput[$parent])? $dbInput[$parent][':id'] : null;

    $dbInput[$title] = [
        ':id'       =>  $id,
        ':parent'   =>  $parent_id,
        ':title'    =>  $title,
    ];
}
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname','usr','pass');

$sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tree (id, parent, title) VALUES (:id, :parent, :title)");
foreach($dbInput as &$input){
    $sth->execute($input);
}
echo 'done';
```

[image]

Comment: Works almost perfect, but the parent_id is always "null". Can't use PDO, since it is in a given framework (oxid). Might be the line with $parent_id what causes the "NULL"-value

Comment: yeah, working with a numerical index works. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Glad you got it working, im intrigued what did you need to change?

Comment: `$parent_id = isset($dbInput[$parent]) ? $dbInput[$parent][0] : "NULL";` since [:id] always returned nothing. Maybe due to PHP 5.3 though

Comment: If two categories have the same name this code will not work. For example, Apple may appear twice for the fruit Apple or the company Apple. You need to make sure this does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you want. This assumes that the parent category must appear before a child.

```
<?php

$s = "# Google_Product_Taxonomy_Version: 2015-02-19
1 - Animals & Pet Supplies
3237 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Live Animals
2 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies
3 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies
7385 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories
499954 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories > Bird Cage Bird Baths
7386 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories > Bird Cage Food & Water Dishes
4989 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cages & Stands
4990 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Food";
$lines = explode("\n", $s);
$ids = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if ($line{0} == '#') continue;
    list($id, $category) = explode(' - ', $line);
    $ids[$category] = $id;
    $pos = strrpos($category, ' > ');
    if ($pos === false) {
        echo "$id has no parent\n";
    } else {
        $parentcat = substr($category, 0, $pos);
        echo "$id has parent " . $ids[$parentcat] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output

`1 has no parent
3237 has parent 1
2 has parent 1
3 has parent 2
7385 has parent 3
499954 has parent 7385
7386 has parent 7385
4989 has parent 3
4990 has parent 3`

https://3v4l.org/Fce8Y

Comment: will give it a shot in a few minutes, thank you already for your effort. Havn't checked the complete file yet, but I just hope that those categories appear first :)

Comment: works good so far. May I ask how I would go for the title as well? For your output 1 has no parent (title of cat1) | 3237 (title of 3237) has parent 1

Comment: the title is obviously `substr($category, 0, $pos + 3)`